# phonegap iOS can't find jQuery mobile map file

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I'm having an issue with jQuery Mobile CSS showing on the iOS simulator.  When I debug in Safari I get an error about a missing min.map file, I'm not using a min file and it's all in a local folder.  I'm using phonegap 4.0, jQuery mobile 1.4.5 .  I generated a new project from command line and copied the www content from my Android project.  All works well with Android and in the local Safari browser.  I've tried the href="./css/  solution.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found the problem, apparently there is a staging folder that is the real source.  I was changing the files in the main project www folder but I noticed the changes never took effect.  Once I updated everything in the staging folder it's fine now.  Is that normal?

Comment: can you provide more details about how you "updated everything in the staging folder"? I hit the same problem now..